# Oracle select from a list of values with an index

Tags: oracle, plsql

Is there an alternative to decode function in oracle which gets and index and a list of values as parameters and returns the value at given index?

Comment: Is the only option for the "list of values" a comma-separated string?  Could you use a collection instead?

Comment: @JustinCave, no it's not the only option, but it shouldn't be stored somewhere in db.

Comment: oops, is there a downvote mafia here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
regexp_substr('value1|value2|value3', '[^|]+', 1, index)
```